# Converting Observable<A[]> to Observable<B[]> in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my angular service I have two working methods:

```
getAObjects(): Observable<A[]>

convert(object: A): Observable<B>
```

These do some asynchronous requests and fetch either a set of A-type objects or a B-type object if an A-type object is given.

Now I want to implement a third method:

```
getBObjects(): Observable<B[]>
```

This should fetch all A-type objects asynchronously and then convert them to B-type objects. This should happen if I press a fetch button, so I would like to subscribe to this new method and all requests should start from there.

So far I have tried the following:

```
getBObjects(): Observable<B[]> {
  const a: Observable<A[]> = getAObjects();
  const b: Observable<Observable<B>[]> = a.map(aList => aList.map(aItem => convert(aItem)));
  const c: Observable<Observable<B>> = b.flatMap(bItem => bItem);
  const d: Observable<B> = c.flatMap(cItem => cItem);
}
```

I would like to use something like flatMap to get rid of the Observable of Observable but to keep the array instead of getting rid of the array. Is that possible or is there a better way to achieve this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `switchMap`.

```
getBObjects(): Observable<B[]> {
    return this.getAObjects().switchMap(as => this.convertAll(as));
}
```

You can do something like this, I think:

```
convertAll(as: A[]): Observable<B[]> {
    return Observable.combineLatest(as.map(a => this.convert(a)));
}
```

See details here:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: combineLatest returns a unary function (src: Observable<{}>): Observable<[{}, Observable<B>] switchMap can't convert the types.

Comment: I tried ```switchMap((as: A[]) => combineLatest(as.map(a => this.convert(a))(this.getAObjects())``` This returned a unary function ```(src: Observable<A[]>): Observable<[{}, Observable<B>]>```

Comment: How about the following:
```getBObjects(): Observable<B[]> {
    return this.getAObjects().pipe(
        switchMap(as: A[] => as.map(a => this.convert(a))),
        combineAll()
    );
}```